# Cached image not being updated with LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file);

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I'm using it in a desktop bridge app. The first time I used it, it set the image correctly. From then on, every time it's executed, it just sets the same first image, no matter which file I point it at. I can even see the correct image in settings->lock-screen. But when I click on it there, I get the cached image instead. Even after a reboot, the first cached image is still the one shown.

Setting the image in other ways (such as from a UWP app) works fine.

**EDIT**

Another strange thing is that when I run the app for the first time, I get:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'

at the `LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync`. But then I just run it again and it doesn't throw that exception.

**More Info**

Targeting and Minimum version are Windows 1903, as is the computer itself. In sign-in options I have "use my sign-in info to automatically..." turned off. I also have hibernation off (and therefore fast startup is disables as well). I have tested this on 2 computers with the same results including the `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: What's your desktop bridge project's target version and OS build version?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT 1809 and 1903 respectively.

Comment: I created a desktop bridge app to test `LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file)` method. It worked well on my side. It will always update the lockScreen image when I set different image for it.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Strange. I now tried on another computer with my same results. I saw, also, that under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\{SID}\ReadOnly` there's a new folder created for every image added through settings, but for images added through my app, they're all in one folder, with the original image as `LockScreen___1920_1080_notdimmed.jpg` and the latest one with all the other names. I'm referencing `windows.winmd` and `system.runtime,windowsruntime`. And using `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path)` to get the file. How do my 2 computers give the same result?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT By `How do my 2 computers give the same result?` I meant: Since I get the same problem on 2 computers, I don't think it's some problem with my computer. So how do you get a different result? Strange.

Comment: Can you post a minimal repro that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT There's nothing more to it than I've posted. On a Click event handler in a WPF app, I have a string `path` which I feed to `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` and then feed the result to `LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync()`. That's all. And the references are as mentioned in my comment above (windows and windowsruntime). Packed with a packaging project.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I also edited my question to include another weird thing - that the file is not found on the first execution of the code. I just created a new solution and it had the same thing happen.

Comment: @ispiro You'd better provide a [mcve] for more diagnosis, instead of one line code `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync()`.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Here: `string path = "thePath"; var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path); await LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file);`. That's all it is.

Comment: I can reproduce this. Looks like a bug to me. @Xavier-MSFT can you please forward this issue to the right team? Btw, this isn't related to desktop-bridge, it repros also with a non-packaged WPF app. Seems like the SetImageFileAsync API has a bug when being called from a non-UWP process.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Thanks for confirming that. While they're at it maybe they can take a look at [UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.trysetlockscreenimageasync) which fails as well, and at the `FileNotFoundException` exception that I added to my question.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I see that Stefan Wick replied to you, but I'm not sure that the `@` was enough to have you receive a notification. Did you see his reply? (2 comments above this one.)

Comment: @ispiro I've reported to the relevant team.

Comment: @XavierXie Is there a way I can see the progress on this issue?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Is there a way I can see the progress on this issue?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Is there any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a bug in Windows.

Thanks [Stefan Wick MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935486/cached-image-not-being-updated-with-lockscreen-setimagefileasyncfile/57047512#comment100576490_56935486).